# How does memory use work in C# when adding the same object to different lists?

Tags: c#, memory

I am developing a game where 2 players each have many objects from a class called UnitObject, each of which can be on a different Army.
Right now, the player class has a List of UnitObjects and at the same time, each Army has its own List  for storing units that belong to it. I am new to c# and I am wondering if, when having hundreds of units, it would be better to have the player have a Dictionary<int, UnitObject> with the int being the id of said unit, so that other classes can have just a List of integers for reference. Do the UnitObjects in the Army duplicate the memory use of the ones in the Player or is it just a reference?
My code could be (very) simplified to:

```
UnitObject unit =  new UnitObject();
army.units.Add(unit)
player.units.Add(unit)
```

This is an over simplification, my classes have other classes they belong to and is not as simple as to make the player have a list of armies or so. I am just wondering if by doing this, i am using double memory for each object.

Comment: If it is a class, it is a reference. You can prove this to yourself by changing one of the references - the other reference to the same object will change (since it is the same object).

Comment: (Interface types are also always treated as references.)

Comment: Does that mean it is ok to keep it as it is? (having each class have a list of units they actually share)

Comment: @user286740 Can you provide some more info on that - I am surprised if a `struct` that implemented an interface acted the way you said it does.

Answer (score 1):

`UnitObject` is a *reference type*, unlike s `struct` or [most] primitive objects such as `int`, which are *value types*.

Reference objects are allocated independently, either on the the stack or the heap (depending). They are passed by reference: when you add an instance of a *reference type* (such as an instance of your `UnitObject`) to a collection, what it added is a *reference* to the actual object itself. A *reference* is a single processor word (32- or 64-bit, depending on processor architecture). It's not a pointer, more like a pointer to a pointer, to allow the allocated object to be moved by the garbage collector if need be.

You when you add an instance of your `UnitObject` to two different collections, they both *point* to the *same instance of `UnitType`*.

And if you pass a reference type to a method, it is passed by reference: any changes made to the passed object by the called function persist once control returns to the caller.

Value types, are passed by *value*, *näturlich*, so adding something like an `int` to a collection means the collection receives a copy of the value. Ditto for passing value types to method: the method receive a copy of the value.